# How to get total of scorecard.run field value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

js
I want to create function that return **total of scorecard.runs**
i tried but it showing  NAN value in browser 
Here id my code

```
mainApp.controller("playerController", function($scope) {


$scope.player = 
   {
      firstName: "Rohit",
      lastName: "Sharma",
      country: "India",

      scorecard:
      [
         {team:'Australlia',run:1255},
         {team:'Srilanka',run:1195},
         {team:'Pakistan',run:2595},

      ],

      totalRuns: function() 
      {
        var total =  0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < $scope.player.scorecard.length ; i++ )
        {
            total += $scope.player.scorecard[i].run; << here
        }
        return total ;
       }


   };
});
```

Thank you

Comment: In the totalRuns function, where are you getting score.run[i] from?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
  total += score.run[i];
```

to

```
  total += $scope.player.scorecard[i].run;
```

I'm not sure if i'm missing something about where you're getting `score.run` from, but it seems based on your logic you are looking for `$scope.player.scorecard[i].run` instead. I'm just assuming this because you are looping on `$scope.player.scorecard.length`.

Also - just a heads up - you have are missing a comma after the fullName function

```
  fullName: function() 
  {
     var playerObject;
     playerObject = $scope.player;
     return playerObject.firstName + " " + playerObject.lastName;
  },    << here
```

Comment: I tried that also but still not showing the expected output

Comment: @KiranChoudhary when you say expected output, what do you mean, and what are you getting as the output right now that is wrong?

Comment: It Simply displaying  "{{player.totalRuns()}}" as it is in browser

Comment: @KiranChoudhary because you are using the wrong syntax {{player.totalRuns}} -- no parens. You should include your html in your question too. I also might recommend you just make this into a model using a .factory, then you can use prototype and make this much easier.

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to increment total runs like this:

```
total += $scope.player.scorecard[i].run;
```